# Gradle dependency resolution

Tags: java, jar, gradle, dependency-management

I have an issue with how gradle resolves my dependencies.

I have four repositories that I need to investigate for different jars, five counting Maven central. Thus my repo statment in gradle.build looks like this:

```
repositories {

  maven {
    url 'urltoRepoA'
    artifactUrls mavenLocal()
  }
  maven {
    url 'urltoRepoB'
    artifactUrls mavenLocal()
  }
  maven {
    url 'urltoRepoC'
    artifactUrls mavenLocal()
  }
  maven {
    url 'urltoRepoD'
    artifactUrls mavenLocal()
  }

  mavenCentral()
}
```

What I want to acheive:
Look for dependencies both in the remote repositories and the local maven repository.

But I get this error below, that is a jar that should be resolved from repoA (repoA is a mirror of maven central, and I have verified that this jar can be found there)

```
[16:43:10][Step 1/3] > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
[16:43:10][Step 1/3]    > Artifact 'junit:junit:4.11@jar' not found.
```

According to what I've read in gradles manual is that it tries to resolve all the dependencies from the same repo. Is that what I'm running in to here? Or have I failed to configure gradle properly?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there is something wrong elsewhere in your gradle configuration. I think you are misunderstanding how gradle resolves artifacts.

According to the [gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) (see section 8.5)

> A project can have multiple repositories. Gradle will look for a
>   dependency in each repository in the order they are specified,
>   stopping at the first repository that contains the requested module.

In fact, it's rather common to have multiple repositories in a gradle script.

Comment: Yeah, I get that as well, what bugs me is this:
`You may configure any number of repositories, each of which is treated independently by Gradle. If Gradle finds a module descriptor in a particular repository, it will attempt to download all of the artifacts for that module from the same repository.` I'm not quite sure what this implies, does this mean that if I depend on artifact A, B and C , and if gradle finds A in the first repo it looks in, will it stop there? or will it also consider the other repos, I get the feeling it doesn't :S

Comment: Gradle will consider the other repositories. What the documentation says is that if Gradle finds a POM in repository A, it also expects to find the corresponding Jar in A. With `artifactUrls` you can make Gradle look in additional repositories for the Jar. `mavenLocal()` should only be used if you need to consume artifacts installed by local Maven builds. Otherwise there is no advantage in using it (only disadvantages). Probably you should just remove all `artifactUrl` lines. If you are still experiencing resolution problems, try with `--refresh-dependencies`.